# What is the difference between the archives and annals of a conference?

Tags: publications, conference, terminology

I would like to know, when publishing a paper in a conference, what are the differences between a publication in the **annals** of the conference and the **archives**?

Comment: Could you give a link to a conference where these two terms are used? (I haven't heard of this before…)

Comment: @Dirk here it is https://www.ipi.uni-hannover.de/519.html

Comment: it says that full paper will be published in annals and accepted abstract can led to a published paper in the archives

Comment: You just answered your own question: A publication in the annals is a full paper, but a publication in the archives is only an abstract.

Comment: Actually both publications are full papers, but now the conference is done, I have my answer: 
publications in the annals are based on reviewed full paper whereas publications in the archives are based on reviewed abstract OR reviewed full papers that where found not strong enough to be in the annals